# sbt, intellij jar in external library but not found when compile

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

encounter a very strange problem.
I'm trying to use reactivemongo. And after update build.sbt
I can see that the jar is in the external library. However the compilation failed because not found object reactivemongo.
[image]

my build.sbt is:

`here`enter code here`lazy val commonSettings = Seq(`
  `here`organization := "emmettng.com",
 here`version := "0.0.1",`
  `scalaVersion := "2.11.8"`
`)`

`here`resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at"http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
resolvers += "Typesafe repository releases" at"http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"`

`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(`
  `"org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.11.8",`
  `"org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.11" % "1.0.4",`
  ``"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test",
  `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.4.0-M3",`
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.5",
  `"junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % "test",`
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.11.14"
`)`

Comment: Check using directly SBT

Comment: Have you ever tried in CLI rather than intellij?